# why React update state function doesn't update state if i callback a function from a parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am praticing react,  so i was designing a basic "skill development course selection" interface for leaners. While doing so ,  i wrote a component which is looped by its parents component.   which represents individual course  to select (single course card )  .   On that course card ([card image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lNX1.png) ) i have a button for seleting course. and i added conditional attributes and classes to change button on certain state update.
On button Click handler,  I updates that state. Normally it works. But i also pass the selected  course data from this component  to root component, through another component (direct father component  of this  component) using function passed  as props . After the function call, for some reason my state, depending on  which my button changes, does not work anymore.
the component:

[codesanbox link of that file](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/mrsnailo/react-practice-applications/tree/main/course-reg?file=/src/components/Courses/Courses.jsx:20,15)

[github repo of that project](https://github.com/mrsnailo/react-practice-applications/tree/main/course-reg)

Then I checked if the updating  state worked, logging the current value stored in the state,  to the console. And it did not update. I can not figure out why .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is in your `CourseList`, you have the components inside the loop with the property of `key` with value of random string.

The `key` is important to let React know whether they should treat one component as a brand new or the old one so it can decide whether to keep of complete refresh the state of the component.

You fix will simply needs to be --

```
const CoursesList = ({ onSelectCourse, jsonData, totalCredit }) => {
  const dataList = jsonData;
  return dataList.map((course, i) => {
    return (
      <Courses
        key={i} // <-- HERE
        {...restOfProps}
      />
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: well, thanks. That solved my issue. But still, I am a bit confused that I had also set the key props, why that didn't work? how does this key works actually?

Comment: "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed." so in your case, because you are assigning different keys for each `Courses` on every re-render, React thinks they are all brand new component, so treats them as new components (reinitialized`isSelected` in every `Courses` component with `false`). React more here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys